# DRF serializer does not send the correct data from the request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I build an API endpoint that talks an `image` as input and print it on the screen, the problem is when I print the `request.data` it gives me the correct data, but when I pass this data to the serializer, DRF change it!

---

**serializer**:

```
class TestUploadImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     images = serializers.ImageField()
     other_data = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**views**:

```
class TestUploadImageApi(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = TestUploadImageSerializer(data=request.data)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    
        print(f'request.data =  {request.data} \n')
        print(f'serializer.data =  {serializer.data} \n')

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

---

I'm using `Postman` to send the image:

[image]

---

This is the output for `request.data` and `serializer.data`

```
request.data =  <QueryDict: {'other_data': ['Test API'], 'images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: ikea3.png (image/png)>]}> 

serializer.data =  {'images': None, 'other_data': 'Test API'}
```

---

So, the question is why `serializer.data` gives me these result?

Comment: You should access serializer.validated_data after validation

Comment: Thanks for your time @gmc , you are right, if I access it via `serializer.validated_data` it works fine. I updated the question and added another field to the serializer `other_data`, and it appears from  `serializer.data` 
 as you can see, unlike images, I'm curious why that happened!

Comment: Binary content is always tricky. I'll assume that DRF removes it from serializer's input data once it's been processed

Comment: Yeah, maybe! thanks again @gmc